# Add custom control to Canvas in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have Canvas as a ListBox's ItemsPanelTemplate.
I Have Ruler custom control.
I need add this Ruler to Canvas, but i can't add itto ItemsPanelTemplate (there could be 1 element).
Is any way to define custom Canvas and add ruler in top and left side of Canvas?
But i dont want add Ruler to Canvas drawing Area, but close to sides.

Comment: You could implement your own Panel type - either by deriving from Canvas or from scratch.  However, it's not easy - a better solution would probably be to have a custom (non-panel) control with the rulers, and then fill in the space between them with your plain canvas and ListBox

Comment: @Andrew I have UserControl with grid, in grid i have listbox and as itemspaneltemplate i have canvas. Tell me, if i set for itemspaneltemplate margin for 50 for example, is any way to insert in this free area my ruler control??

Comment: no, you cannot add your own controls to the itemspaneltemplate in any reasonable way (I think some unreasonable ways exist)- but why do you have to have the rulers on the canvas?  can't they exist in the grid that contains the items control?

Comment: @Andrew here is my problem screenshot : http://i58.tinypic.com/20z8vn5.png   I need to scroll rulers together with canvas, but canvas is a itemspaneltemplate for listbox. and there is scrollbar.i have no idea how solve it

Comment: I'd have to think about how to solve that - but I would also say that embedding the rulers in the canvas would not produce a good result since the rulers would only be visible when the scrollbars are at the edge.

Comment: yep... you realized me about next problem... i can show you my xaml code if needed. thanks